# Neutral word for saying that a task is finished, without denoting success or failure

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, programming, computing

I'm working on some code where a task has two result states:

```
- Complete | The task completed successfully
- Failure  | The task failed to complete successfully (no further attempts will be made)
```

The actual implementation has more to it than this, but it really comes down to success or failure.

I have a number of convenience methods for checking the state of the task, such as `isComplete` and `isFailed`.

I need one that essentially answers the question:

> "Has the task reached a final state where it is no longer running and will not resume at any time in the future."

Or, in pseudocode:

```
isComplete() or isFailed()
```

I find myself having trouble choosing the final name for this method. All the candidates I've written down seem to hint towards a positive or negative outcome. They are:

- `+` Finished
- `+` Done
- `+` Processed
- `-` Stopped
- `-` Terminated
- `+` Finalized
- `+` Processed
- `-` Attempted

I feel the latter three have the most potential here, but I welcome any suggestions.

---

**Note:** I have read [Words for resulting task states in computing [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399278/words-for-resulting-task-states-in-computing), however it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Why not define *success* as the antonym to *failure*? You can then have `isComplete()` as the answer to your question, along with `isSuccessful()` and `isFailed()`.

Comment: How about "ended"?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite common to call such a state **closed**. With the meaning of the *final* state, not regarding whether the task/issue has been solved, failed, rejected or whatever. It is very common in the various [work flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow) and [issue tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system) tools.

Have a look at some pictures here: https://www.google.com/search?q=tracking+issue+state+diagram&tbm=isch

But still consider @AndrewLeach's comment (*complete* as the answer to your question, along with *successed* and *failed*), it sounds quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more synonyms:

- Completed  #Sounds a bit "success-ish"
- Finished   #Sounds a bit "success-ish"
- Concluded
- Ended
- Stopped    #Can indicate external effect